# How can an instance of a timeout function be exited?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say you want to create a java function with setTimeout so that it repeats every 5 seconds. This timed function is just updating some data. The call occurs when the users clicks a button that opens an overlay, and the function will continue to run as long as the overlay is open. abandonUpdate is set to true once the overlay is closed, and this is checked in the timer function. However if the user opens the overlay before the timeout completes, it will add on another instance of the timeout function.

How can this be avoided?

http://jsfiddle.net/m6LAL/1/

(By the way the timer does not seem to work on jsfiddle or bin.. the same code works on my server however.. )

```
var abandonUpdate = true;

function timers(){
    if(!abandonUpdate){
        $('.timeout').css({"background-color":'#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16)});
        setTimeout("timers()", 5000);
    }
}

$('.timeout').click(function(){
    abandonUpdate = false;
    console.log("Hello I'm running");
    timers(); 
});
```

Comment: It is working -- just set `setTimeout("timers()", 5000)` to `setTimeout(timers, 5000);` http://jsfiddle.net/6nLC3/

Comment: why not use `setInterval` instead, and `clearInterval` when you want to remove the "timer"?

Comment: @Goose That's probably a good idea.
Also, `while ((Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16).length === 6);` terminates, which indicates that `(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16)` may not be a valid color

Comment: If you're going to *create a java function*, you should use *Java*, **not** *Javascript*. Which are not in the slightest the same thing.

Comment: `clearTimeout` deserves attention too

Comment: @Jared Farrish Yeah - it's not like they start with the same word, or that one is derived from the other.

Comment: I totally blame Netscape for that. It's common for beginners to do so, but around SO and more seasoned developers, it's best not to confuse the two (as it annoys *both* camps).

Comment: Oh and just to be sure, one is *absolutely, positively, negatory* derived from the other. They are not related in any way. Period. It's believed Netscape copped the name because they wanted to give it credence (and Java was *hot* at the time it was named), but Javascript is somewhat a derivation of a language called [Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(programming_language)), which is in the LISP family.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let look at a straight demonstration:

```
var loops = 0,
    to = setTimeout(function test(){
        console.log('Test run ' + ++loops + ' times.');

        if (loops < 100) {
            to = setTimeout(test, 3000);
        }
    }, 3000),
    check = setTimeout(function check(){
        console.log('Test checked (' + loops + ').');

        if (loops > 10) {
            console.log('Test setTimeout aborted.');

            clearTimeout(to);

            return;
        }

        setTimeout(check, 500);
    });
```

What we have here are two regenerating `setTimeout()`s, each of which does something slightly different. The first, using the `var to`, runs the `test()` function, which is what we're trying to preempt (or abort, if you will).

The second, `var check`, runs more frequently (1/2 second as opposed to 3 seconds). The second is monitoring the iterations of `test()` and "cancels" (or "clears") the `test()` timeout, using the captured reference `var to`.

Note how I've captured the reference within `test()` when it regenerates the timeout? If you *don't* do this, you get an infinite loop; each reference returned by `setTimeout()` changes, so you have to be careful to capture the reference to the same variable that both functions have access to. Otherwise, you "clear" the timeout of one that has possibly/probably already ended.

The alternative, of course, is to use `setInterval()`, which *always uses the same reference when it runs*, and thus `clearInterval(to)` would work and you don't have to worry about keeping `to` set to the right reference. I would consider this preferential; use `setInterval()` here, not `setTimeout()`. There are times it makes sense to regenerate, but I don't think it does here.

```
var intl;

function timers() {
    $('.timeout').css({
        "background-color": '#' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16)
    });
}

$('.timeout').click(function(){
    if (intl) {
        clearInterval(intl);
        console.log("I stopped goodbye!");
        intl = 0;
    } else {
        console.log("Hello I'm running!");
        intl = setInterval(timers, 5000); // Pass the test reference, not "test()";
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m6LAL/2/

Comment: Thanks. What does it mean to pass a reference? You explain things well.

Comment: When you create a function like `function test(){}`, it's stored somewhere in memory. This means it's like a box with a number on it; this memory-box-number can be used as a *reference* to say, "call what's at this reference". When you call `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`, when you pass a string ("test()"), it will be *eval'd* as an expression, which is slow and potentially problematic. Instead, give it a reference to the function by passing only the *name* (and not the `()`, which will run it automatically and pass what it returns to `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`). It's a pro tip.

Comment: Ah! But what if that function takes args?

Comment: You might read [MDN's *Syntax* section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) for `setTimeout()`, which explains the difference (and recommends not using the eval'd *code* method.

Comment: `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()`-referenced functions don't take arguments. But if you need to call a function you've passed as a reference and/or want to share scope, use either [`func.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`func.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), depending on what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `setInterval`, so you don't need to keep recreating the timeout; save the return value, and use `clearInterval` when the overlay closes:

```
var interval = setInterval(work, 1000)
close_button.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(interval)
}
```

[Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/zv2mD/)

And as @Jared mentions, javascript is not the same as Java :) fortunately...